# Server.CreateObject("MSWC.ContentRotator") error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, adrotator

I'm migrating a classic asp website from iis6 (Windows Server 2003) to iis7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2). It uses the content rotator. The schedule is tight so I would prefer not to replace the content rotator at this time. I copied adrot.dll to the new server and successfully registered it with regsvr32. Dependency Walker did not identify any issues with adrot.dll. Any idea what is causing the error?

line causing error:
Set objContentRotator = Server.CreateObject("MSWC.ContentRotator")

error message:
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
Server.CreateObject Failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the ad rotator to work on iis 7.5. After placing adrot.dll in the sysWOW64 directory and registering it with regsvr32 it still did not work even with read and execute permission for "Everyone". What got it working was to grant read and execute permission to "Anonymous Logon".

Answer (score 2):

ContentRotator was included in Win2003 IIS6.  I'm afraid it doesn't ship with Win 2008 IIS7.  You either need to find the relevant dll - its called mswcrun.dll - on your old server, copy to the new one and register it, of find another way of rotating your content